# BigQuery SQL - a way to pass values from more than one row and more than one column to User Defined Function

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to create a User Defined Function, (`CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION`) in BigQuery Standard SQL which will accept values aggregated from a bunch of rows.

My schema and table is similar to this:

```
| c1    | c2    | c3    | c4    |
|=======|=======|=======|=======|
| 1     | 1-1   | 3A    | 4A    |
| 1     | 1-1   | 3B    | 4B    |
| 1     | 1-1   | 3C    | 4C    |
| 1     | 1-2   | 3D    | 4D    |
| 2     | 2-1   | 3E    | 4E    |
| 2     | 2-1   | 3F    | 4F    |
| 2     | 2-2   | 3G    | 4G    |
| 2     | 2-2   | 3H    | 4H    |
```

I can't change the original schema to be made of nested or ARRAY fields.

I want to group by `c1` and by `c2` and pass values of `c3` and `c4` to a function, while being able to match between values from `c3` and `c4` for each row.
One way of doing so is using `ARRAY_AGG` and pass values as an `Array`, but `ARRAY_AGG` is non-deterministic so values from `c3` and `c4` might come with different orders than the source table.
`Example`:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION
    tempConcatStrFunction(c3 ARRAY<STRING>, c4 ARRAY<STRING>)
    RETURNS STRING
    LANGUAGE js AS """
       return
        c3
        .map((item, index) => [ item, c4[index] ].join(','))
        .join(',');
    """;
WITH T as (
    SELECT c1, c2, ARRAY_AGG(c3) as c3, ARRAY_AGG(c4) as c4
    GROUP BY c1, c2
)
SELECT c1, c2, tempConcatStrFunction(c3, c4) as str from T
```

The result should be:

```
| c1    | c2    | str                  |
|=======|=======|======================|
| 1     | 1-1   | 3A,4A,3B,4B,3C,4C    |
| 1     | 1-2   | 3D,4D                |
| 2     | 2-1   | 3E,4E,3F,4F          |
| 2     | 2-2   | 3G,4G,3H,4H          |
```

Any ideas how to achieve such results?

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas how to achieve such results?

I understand your question is about how to keep c3 and c4 match each other in final string. How about just keep it super simple as below

```
SELECT c1, c2, STRING_AGG(CONCAT(c3, ',', c4)) AS str
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY c1, c2
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of examples that may help with setting up a query:

```
WITH T AS (
  SELECT 1 AS c1, '1-1' AS c2, '3A' AS c3, '4A' AS c4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '1-1', '3B', '4B' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '1-1', '3C', '4C' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '1-2', '3D', '4D' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2-1', '3E', '4E' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2-1', '3F', '4F' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2-2', '3G', '4G' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2-2', '3H', '4H'
)
SELECT
  c1,
  c2,
  STRING_AGG(CONCAT(c3, ',', c4)) AS str
FROM T
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

This takes the unaggregated inputs (as in Mikhail's answer) and does string concatenation.

If the inputs are already aggregated into arrays, ideally they would repeat together, e.g.:

```
WITH T AS (
  SELECT 1 AS c1, '1-1' AS c2, '3A' AS c3, '4A' AS c4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '1-1', '3B', '4B' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '1-1', '3C', '4C' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '1-2', '3D', '4D' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2-1', '3E', '4E' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2-1', '3F', '4F' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2-2', '3G', '4G' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2-2', '3H', '4H'
),
U AS (
  SELECT
    c1,
    c2,
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(c3, c4)) AS arr
  FROM T
)
SELECT
  c1,
  c2,
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT(c3, ',', c4)) FROM UNNEST(arr)) AS str
FROM U
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

If the arrays are separate, but have a consistent order (and length), you can recombine them after the fact:

```
WITH T AS (
  SELECT 1 AS c1, '1-1' AS c2, '3A' AS c3, '4A' AS c4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '1-1', '3B', '4B' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '1-1', '3C', '4C' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '1-2', '3D', '4D' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2-1', '3E', '4E' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2-1', '3F', '4F' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2-2', '3G', '4G' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2-2', '3H', '4H'
),
U AS (
  SELECT
    c1,
    c2,
    ARRAY_AGG(c3 ORDER BY c3, c4) AS arr3,
    ARRAY_AGG(c4 ORDER BY c3, c4) AS arr4
  FROM T
  GROUP BY 1, 2 
)
SELECT
  c1,
  c2,
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT(arr4[OFFSET(off)], ',', c3))
   FROM UNNEST(arr3) AS c3 WITH OFFSET off) AS str
FROM U;
```